# Can the expectation of a continuous random variable be negative?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value

I'm given this pdf:

$f(y)= \frac{1}{2}(1-y^3), -1<y<1 , 0 $ elsewhere.

I've computed the expected value which gives $-\frac{1}{5}$ and I'm wondering if an expected value can actually be negative.
Any sort of help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What makes you think it can't be negative?

Comment: What about $f(y)=1$ for $-1 \le y \le 0$, $0$ elsewhere? It's probabilities that can never be negative, but expected values, for sure: You can have a guaranteed negative outcome, loss, ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a random variable $X$, with expectation $1$.

Now $Y:=X-2$ is also a random variable and has expectation $-1$.

Of course, the expectation of a *non-negative* random variable cannot be negative.